# Change css of parent after completing an event

Tags: css

```html
<div class="pane">
  <div style="background-color: #f00">
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="radio1" checked />
    <label for="radio1">Radio 1</label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="select" id="radio2" />
    <label for="radio2">Radio 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make an event: if an `input[type=radio]` is clicked, change css `background-color` of the parent (`<div>`). How can I do that?

Something like:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked < div {
    background-color: #f00
}
```

Is there a way to do that without setting an `id` for per `<div>`?

p/s: I also don't want to use javascript or jquery to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no parent selector in css, so you can't. You can try styling the input or the label.

You could try a sibling selector and absolutely position a sibling element behind your input.

EDIT: example with sibling element `.inputbg`:

https://jsfiddle.net/pfv77ghe/

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately **this cannot be achieved** with current CSS features (hopefully this will be taken care of in the future versions). Right Now this can be done only using Javascript or Jquery.

CSS supports only `child selector from a parent` and **not** a `parent selector from child`.

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

**I think this would work for you.**

```
<input type="click" checked>
```

### CSS

```
input[type= click]:checked+div{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```